# How change attribute "files" (input type=file) in Mozilla

Tags: jquery, forms, file, input

I have problem with my `input type=file`. I uploaded file using jQuery
and now I'm trying to set it in this input, in Google Chrome there is no problem, but in Mozilla and IE it doesn't work.

Below is a few line of my code:

```
obj.on('drop', function (e){
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    $('input[type=file]').prop('files',files);
}
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: When I changing the attribute nothing happen, input remains empty. It happens only on Mozilla and IE.